# Linq to entities join not working

Tags: c#, .net, linq, entity-framework, linq-to-entities

Any idea why the following code will not compile?

```
IEnumerable users;
using (var ent = new GatekeeperEntities())
{
    users = from t1 in ent.Users
            join t2 in ent.UserStatus1 on t1.ID equals t2.UserId
            where t2.ExpirationDateTime != null
            select new {t1.ID, t1.Name, t1.UserName, t2.Status };
    }

foreach (var user in users)
{
    user.ID; // Cannot resolve symbol ID
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Restructure your code as below.

```
using (var ent = new GatekeeperEntities())
{
    var users = from t1 in ent.Users
        join t2 in ent.UserStatus1 on t1.ID equals t2.UserId
        where t2.ExpirationDateTime != null
        select new {t1.ID, t1.Name, t1.UserName, t2.Status };

    foreach (var user in users)
    {
        user.ID;
    }
}
```

Comment: Even when defining `users` as `var` instead of  `IEnumerable`?

Comment: Did you remember to use var in place of IEnumerable?

Answer (score 1):

The contents of an `IEnumerable` are of type System.Object, you need to use the var keyword instead so that the compiler will infer that users is of type `IEnumerable<T>` for some anonymous type T. If you want to use an anonymous type, loop over the elements inside the scope of the using block.

Answer (score 0):

```
  user.Id; <-----Cannot resolve symbol ID
```

According to your code it should be `user.ID` (upper case not lower case) - capitalization matters.

Also you have `user` declared as `IEnumerable` - so you won't get any properties of the type it really is, just the properties available on `IEnumerable` - declare it as var and use it inside the using statement, or create a class instead of using an anonymous type.

Comment: Sorry, I fixed it, it is user.ID.  Same error.  It won't intellisense out any of the properties.

Answer (score 0):

Try to cast your user object within the loop.

```
foreach (var user in users)   
{
    ((User)user).ID;
}
```

Answer (score -1):

And remember: what you usually accomplish with joins in SQL, can be simply done by moving along relations in EF:

```
users = from t2 in ent.UserStatus.Include("User") 
where t2.ExpirationDateTime != null
select t2
```

This gives you the `UserStatus`es you want, and you can access the `User` of each `UserStatus` through the property `User` that is propabely defined in your model.